# Window moving function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to move a window a specific amount of pixels on a set timer.
Right now I'm having my startWindow function (which contains the move window function) hold a timer that should move the window every .35 seconds. But for some reason that I cannot figure out it is not working. By the way this is a homework assignment so if possible please do not give me the full answer, just suggestions please. This is the code I am having issues with:

```
    <head>
        <script>
            var aWindow;
            var current = 0;
            function openWindow() {
                aWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height = 200");
                aWindow.document.write("This is my new Window");
            }

            function closeWindow(){
                if(aWindow) {
                    aWindow.close();
                }
            }

            var moveWindow = function windowMove() {
                    if (aWindow) {
                    aWindow.moveTo(100, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(200, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(300, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(400, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(500, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(600, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(700, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(800, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(900, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 0);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 100);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000,  200);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000,  300);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000,  400);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000,  500);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 600);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 700);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 800);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 900);
                    aWindow.moveTo(1000, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(900, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(800, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(700, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(600, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(500, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(400, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(300, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(200, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(100, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 1000);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 900);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 800);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 700);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 600);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 500);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 400);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 300);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 200);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 100);
                    aWindow.moveTo(0, 0);

                }
                function startWindow(){
                    if (timer){ 
                        timer = setInterval(moveWindow(), 350);
                    }
                }
                function stopWindow() {
                clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }

</script>
</head>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openWindow();">Open</button>
        <button onclick="closeWindow();">Close</button>
        <button onclick="startWindow();">Move</button>
        <button onclick="stopWindow();">Stop</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, could also include the openWindow() function in your code? It would be helpful to see how this is being defined. Is the openWindow() function where the aWindow variable is created? The If statement checking aWindow, is it part of the moveWindow() function?

Comment: I added it in, i'm trying to have the if statement move the window then the timer will just loop the moveWindow() function.

Comment: I would post an answer but, since you noted homework: I suggest promise here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Please fix the invalid HTML, verify that is NOT the issue and if not  edit to clear that issue up in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here are a few suggestions:

In order to create a time delay between your function calls, you can use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

In the links you can found basic examples so you can understand how each one works, but my guess is that `await` will solve your issue.

If you wanna stick to the `setInterval` method, you can create an array with your values and call a update function that will increase an index and call each value on the array.

And I really recommend using [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead of inline events.

Comment: eventListeners would probably save me a few lines, would it still work with the rest of my code though?

Comment: If you read the event listener API you will realize you can always switch between inline and listeners as long as you only have one event per element.